# Django objects.filter issues

Tags: python, django, object, django-models

I get this error: **`Cannot assign "[<Response: Response object>, <Response: Response object>]": "Comment.response" must be a "Response" instance`.** How do I assign response to an instance by matching applicant and interview id?
Also, I only want the first response out of all the possible results from objects.filter()

```
def post_comment(request, interview_id, applicant_id):
  if request.POST:
    text = str(request.POST['add_comment'])
    interview = Interview.objects.get(id = interview_id)
    applicant = Applicant.objects.get(id = applicant_id)
    response = Response.objects.filter(interview = interview, applicant = applicant)
    date = datetime.datetime.now()
comment = Comment(
  user = request.user,
  applicant = applicant,
  interview = interview,
  response = response,
  comment = text,
  created_at = date,
)
```

My models are as follows:

```
class Response(models.Model):
  video_guid = models.CharField(max_length=32)
  interview = models.ForeignKey(Interview)
  applicant = models.ForeignKey(Applicant)
  question = models.ForeignKey(Question)


class Comment(models.Model):
  user = models.ForeignKey(User)
  applicant = models.ForeignKey(Applicant)
  interview = models.ForeignKey(Interview)
  response = models.ForeignKey(Response)
  comment = models.TextField(default='')
  created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now())
```

I'm new to Django :( Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

The problem you have is that your filter is returning multiple results; not just the "first" or the "last" (since you didn't specify such a condition).

The second issue is that your model does not allow multiple responses for each comment.

You have a few choices:

1. Adjust your model to allow multiple responses for each comment. To do that, change `response = models.ForeignKey(Response)` to `response = models.ManyToMany(Response)` (see [`ManyToMany`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/)) then you adjust your view. First create a `Comment` object, then `comment.response.add()` each response.
2. Create multiple `comment` objects for each of the response entries. This may not be ideal; but it will work without having to migrate your database schema.

Here is how it would look:

```
for i in response:
    Comment.objects.create(
           user = request.user,
           applicant = applicant,
           interview = interview,
           response = i,
           comment = text,
           created_at = date)
```

Your models have redundant fields that you don't need. Since `Comment` has a relationship with `Response`, you don't need to duplicate the fields in `Response` in your `Comment` model. You can [follow relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships) and get the related fields:

```
c = Comment.objects.get(pk=1)
c.response.interview # interview object

# Get all the comments for where the interview objects primary key is 1
c = Comment.objects.filter(response__interview__pk=1)

r = Response.objects.get(pk=1)
r.comment_set.all() # all comments for this response
```

Before you sit and write your models, write down what kind of queries you need to do against the database. This will help you decide what fields (and what relationships) are needed. For example, right now there is no way to get the "first" or "last" response for a particular interview (since there is no date field in `Response`).

Comment: I would add that even if a single response was returned by filter, it would still error, as a filter returns a "list" of results, even if there is only a single response.

Answer (score 1):

As your query `Response.objects.filter(interview = interview, applicant = applicant)` is returning `list` with two Response Object in it, is cannot be assigned to Comment.response which is FK to response.

ForeignKey can only store reference (id) to single record of other Table/Model.

Comment: How can I select just the first result from the list returned?I tried Response.objects.filter(interview = interview, applicant = applicant) [0] which didn't work..